# Batch script to delete foldernames with specified number of characters

Tags: batch-file, directory

I need a batch script to delete folders with a length = 2. All of folders are located in specifed directory. The folders with length different than 2 have to stay in place.
Example:

```
Dir C:\Test
```

Subdir to delete:

```
    01
    02
    .
    .
    25
    .
    etc.
```

Comment: you mean name length?

Comment: yes, it means name length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming sub-directories are in the same directory as the script.
Unfortunately simply `dir /a:d /b "??"` will include also one letter dirs and you need to calculate the [name length](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=424).Will try with better usage of wildcards.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%# in ('dir /a:d /b "??"') do ( 
    set "dirn=%%~n#"
    call :strlen0 dirn len
    if !len! equ 2 rd /s /q "%%~fn#"
)

exit /b 0

:strlen0  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

**Edit** with filtering with FINDSTR (check also  [aschipfl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) comment ):

```
@echo off


for /f %%# in ('dir /a:d /b "??"^|findstr /i /v /r "^.$"') do ( 
    rd /s /q "%%~fn#"
)
```

Comment: Instead of determining the string length of the dir. name, you could simply compare if `"!dirn!" == "!dirn:~0,1!"` and skip deletion (`rd`) in case.

Comment: @aschipfl - aah - clever.But why I should skip the `rd` as this is what the OP asked for?

Comment: I mean, only in case of equality (which is true if the dir. name is 1 char. long); if the comparison fails, don't skip `rd`.

Comment: What if script will be outside ?

Comment: @Artec add pushd `"c:\somedit"` before the for loop and `popd` after

Comment: @npocmaka Great job. Works perfecly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @npocmaka, even cleverer using `findstr`, I like that (+1); it's (almost) a one-liner and avoids delayed expansion.